# How to sort based on alphanumeric values using java?

Tags: java

I'm having 3 values like

```
a^100,b^200,c^150
```

I need to sort these values in the order of

```
b^200,c^150,a^100
```

How can i do this in java?

Comment: From your example I don't understand how the values are meant to be sorted. Could you describe the sorting rule?

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a sort using Java or for an algorithm to compare "a^100" and "b^200" correctly?

Comment: get the integer after ^ like 100,200,150.compare those values,sort and give the results as 200,150,100.

Comment: All i need is after giving input as a^100,b^200,c^150
the result should be like this:"b should come first,follows by c finally a.Sort based on the value that was given after ^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom `Comparator`, like this one:

```
public class IntegerSubstringCompare implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String left, String right) {
        Integer leftInt = Integer.parseInt(left.substring(left.indexOf("^") + 1));
        Integer rightInt = Integer.parseInt(right.substring(right.indexOf("^") + 1));

        return -1 * leftInt.compareTo(rightInt);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] input = {"a^100", "b^200", "c^150"};
    List<String> inputList = Arrays.asList(input);
    Collections.sort(inputList, new IntegerSubstringCompare());
    System.out.println(inputList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String sample = "a^100,b^200,c^150";
List data = Arrays.asList(sample.split(","));
Collections.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder( new Comparator<String>() {
public int compare (String obj1,String obj2)
{
  String num1 = obj1.split("\\^")[1];
  String num2 = obj2.split("\\^")[1];
  return  num1.compareTo(num2);
}
}));
String sortedSample[]= (String[])data.toArray(new String[data.size()]);
for (int z=0; z< sortedSample.length;z++ )
System.out.println(sortedSample[z]);
```